# Change formatting of paragraphed footnote style in manyfoot

Tags: footnotes, memoir, manyfoot

I have a document with three registers of footnotes, two plain and indented, and one paragraphed. See the example below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}


\usepackage[perpage,ruled,para]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}

\begin{document}

\footnote{We have the default footnote register taken care of by memoir, with formatting options for hanging footnotes applied.}
\footnoteA{Then we have a second register of footnotes.}
\footnoteA{While having an alphabetic counter which is reset per page, it is also a plain footnote register, and automatically takes over the formatting options of the default register handled by memoir, which is fine.}
\footnoteB{Third register, paragraphed. I'd like this to fit better to the other two.}
\footnoteB{I would like to change the format of the footnote marker in the footnote to \textbf{not} be superscript and small.}
\footnoteB{Here the 3 is not indented. I would like to get rid of the indentation for footnote 1, too. There should be a small space after the number though, and probably I want to set it in bold.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Having both default and and B register use numbers is an issue only in this MWE, in the real file they don't occur on the same pages.

Comment: Got rid of the indentation of the third register by using the `para*` option of `manyfoot` instead of only `para` when loading the package.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using the `para*` option of manyfoot to get rid of the initial indentation and then redefining `\footnoteB`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}


\usepackage[perpage,ruled,para*]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\renewcommand{\footnoteB}[1]{\footnotemarkB
\FootnotetextB{}{\textbf{\thefootnoteB}\quad #1}%
}


\begin{document}

\footnote{We have the default footnote register taken care of by memoir, with formatting options for hanging footnotes applied.}
\footnoteA{Then we have a second register of footnotes.}
\footnoteA{While having an alphabetic counter which is reset per page, it is also a plain footnote register, and automatically takes over the formatting options of the default register handled by memoir, which is fine.}
\footnoteB{Third register, paragraphed. I'd like this to fit better to the other two.}
\footnoteB{I would like to change the format of the footnote marker in the footnote to \textbf{not} be superscript and small.}
\footnoteB{Here the 3 is not indented. I would like to get rid of the indentation for footnote 1, too. There should be a small space after the number though, and probably I want to set it in bold.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Changed output]